# Is there a list of all the created views?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering if there is a place where you can see all views that get created using

```
Ext.create
```

or is there a way to check if a view is already created by using its MyApp.view.ViewName?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it but, this could work.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getViews

```
this.getApplication().getViews();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems to only return the views pushed on the viewport, and i would like a list of all the views that get created.
I think sencha needs to keep a reference to each created view somewhere, for autodestroy etc...
But thanks for your time

Comment: Yeah, right. Well, I'm actually facing the same problem for my work so, if you ever find out let me know.